# VPN Software that allow tunneling only for a specific application on windows

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

**Goal : Tunnel specific application(s)'s connection(s) through a vpn**

1. I want to know what vpn software application(s) would allow me to make only specific applications' connections to go through a vpn?
2. What is the minimum knowledge needed in order to be able to configure such vpn software application? (tutorial link as well as software simulation suggestions would be appreciated)